# How to count adjacent polygons in postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgis sql query that fetches polygons from a table and merges adjacent polygons (that share an edge) into larger polygons.

```
SELECT (ST_DUMP(ST_UNION(ST_SNAPTOGRID(geom,0.0001)))).geom
FROM table;
```

How can I get the amount of adjacent polygons that are being merged for each superpolygon?